# Perl: Print the hash value by index

Tags: perl

I use below code and has below result:

```
my $a="A";
my $b="B";
my @array1=qw(4 5 6 7);

my %hash1= ($a => 123, $b => $array1);

use Data::Printer;
p %hash1;
```

Result:

```
{
    A   123,
    B   undef
}
```

But I want to have following result, the $array1 is successfully load in.
how should I modify my code?

```
{
    A   123,
    B   [
          [0] 4,
          [1] 5,
          [2] 6,
          [3] 7
        ]
}
```

Comment: Seen `Data::Dumper`?

Comment: `$array1` is a variable with no relation to `@array1`... ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Instead of a scalar variable `$array1` you want in your hash a reference to the array variable `@array1` (a completely different variable, unrelated to `$array1`) -- so `$b => \@array1`.

Comment: @JeffHolt: He's already using [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer) which is generally considered better than Data::Dumper.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use an array reference to the array that you created:

```
my %hash1= ($a => 123, $b => \@array1);
```

The `$array1` is a scalar variable of the same name, but in a different "namespace". You can have the same name for a scalar, array, hash, subroutine, and so on and those different variables with the same name do not affect each other. Each of `$x`, `@x`, `%x`,  `sub x`, and so on are separate.